Lizmap vector labels and server tile cache
I'm using Lizmap 3.8.2 with QGIS Server 3.38.3
I have several vector layers with labels for each feature, and I'm trying to use the server tile cache.  When I activate caching for a layer, it seems to repeat the label for each tile (left on screen shot), rather than one label per feature (right on screen shot).
I read in the docs that

For vector layers with metatiles, you have to set label position to a fixed position.

But I'm not sure exactly how to implement this, or if this is even the cause.  Currently, the label placement is set to "Around Centroid."  Experimenting with different metatile values didn't seem to change anything.

